# Application Lags

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an android application that allows users to create edit text dynamically. However, it seems that whenever I have more than 5 edit text the typing process gets really lagging.

It goes by having a simple layout and a button. Whenever the button is clicked it runs this code:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
myLayout.addView(editText);
```

Is there any way I can make the code more efficient such that it won't be slow?

Comment: are you running this in the emulator or on a actual device?

Comment: @slayton it runs on a samsung galaxy tab 10.1

Comment: I assume you have an error in the code you wrote here, as you wrote myLayout.addView(context); instead of myLayout.addView(editText);

Comment: @IncrediApp sorry about that, i have that changed already. but my question still remains the same. the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
myLayout.addView(editText);
```

Comment: sorry about that mistake. made changes to the question already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a good idea as I don't know the nature of your app, but declaring views in the xmls is usually faster. Try declaring a bulk of editTexts - according to your average application needs and set their visibility to GONE until the user chooses to add an editText and then you check if you have a GONE view - you set it to visible, If not, you add it via code.
Again, it all depends on your application's needs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the nature of the app is to create a table where the users can add row one by one. for each table row it will consist of an edittext declared in the xml. whenever the user clicks add, i will add the table row to the tablelayout.

Comment: I see. Try adding 5 editText via the xml files and see if it helps, as you mentioned that 5 editTexts added via code is starting to cause performance issues

Comment: i understand what you are trying to mean, but, it won't be work the way it is suppose to be. since every click of add row, adds one row.

Comment: So you didn't understand me completely. Let's say you define 5 initial edittexts in the layout xml. You can set their visibility to GONE by calling editText.setVisibility(View.GONE) on each of them or by defining android:visibility="gone" in the xml layout. Then, when the user adds a row, you check if you have an available "gone" edittext (if the count of rows is less than 5) and all you do is set it to visible by calling: editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). If you don't have a gone view, you create a new one in code.

Comment: ohh, okay. you mean to reduce the number of calling to create a new edit text.

Comment: i just realized that my app is a little weird now. now it doesn't lag at all, even with many other apps running. but there are times when it runs alone, it still lags.

Comment: I mean to move the creation of the edit texts from the code to the layout xml file as it could be faster